# Error al recorrer ArrayList java

Tags: java

```
    private ArrayList GetIC (){
    ArrayList<Sorpresa> molde;
    molde = new ArrayList <>();

    for (Sorpresa t : juego.getMazo()){
        if (t.GetTipo() == TipoSorpresa.IRACASILLA){
            molde.add(new Sorpresa(t.GetTexto(),t.GetValor(),t.GetTipo()));
        }
    }


    return molde;
}
```

Seguramente mi error sea una barbaridad porque soy principiante, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: ¿Dónde está el objeto `juego` que usas aquí: `juego.getMazo()` ?  También, me parece que tu variable `molde` podrías crearla así: `molde = new ArrayList <Sorpresa>();`

Comment: En java 7 con el operador diamante, ya no hace falta repetir el tipo de clase en el constructor. `//Java 6 style
List<String> java6List = new ArrayList<String>();`    `//Java 7 style
List<String> java7List = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le daría mas versatilidad a tu código el usar la interfaz List en lugar de ArrayList.

`List <Sorpresa> molde;`

Tambien recalcar lo que dice A.Cedano, el objeto juego está implementado?¿

¿Y por qué creas un nuevo objeto `Sorpresa` si el foreach ya te está dando uno?,en lugar de :

`molde.add(new Sorpresa(t.GetTexto(),t.GetValor(),t.GetTipo()));`

Podrías hacer esto:

`molde.add(t);`

Comment: Muchas gracias!! . He puesto `molde.add(t);` y todo perfecto.

Comment: Me alegro! Por favor marca la respuesta como válida para que otros con la misma duda puedan beneficiarse, saludos!